# Pass array as a parameter to another

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a code snippet. & i wanted to pass msg_arr as a parameter,array name is msg_arr

Here is my try 1,but getting eror

```
 private void check(string keyword params arr[] msg_arr )
    {
        switch (keyword.ToUpper())
        {
            case  "SETTELG":
                Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arr" + msg_arr);

                break;
```

Here is my try 2,also error

```
 private void check(string keyword string msg_arr[] )
    {
        switch (keyword.ToUpper())
        {
            case  "SETTELG":
                Response.Redirect("../SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?value=1&arr" + msg_arr);

                break;
```

Comment: Why are you guessing? Find a book, and read up on what you can do, before just blindly trying things.

Comment: `but getting eror` What error? When asking a question please include the error you are getting.

Comment: @L.B: The error is pretty obvious in this case ;p

Comment: @leppie Of course, my comment was for future questions

Comment: @leppie i'm still a beginner to c# thats why small things also posted here.because there are lots of professionals there know

Comment: You are missing comma (,) between your two parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are missing a comma between the parameters:

```
private void check(string keyword, params arr[] msg_arr)
```

If that's not the case, please post the whole code and the actual error message. A good idea is to read the [documentation on params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

Comment: i use like this , private void check(string keyword, params Array[] msg_arr)  is tht ok know ? arr to Array ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Learner,

Please use this signature

```
 private void check(params object[] msg_arr)
{

}
```

it works for me hope it also help you

Comment: actually what is object[] here ?

Comment: object accept any type of parameter.You can send array,single parameter or any thing else.